# After two concurrent processes are finished executing, what is the minimum and maximum value of their shared variable?

Tags: operating-system, synchronization, critical-section

Processes P1 and P2 are executing concurrently. They each have a private variable i and both use the shared variable count, which is initialized to zero.

Thread T1:

```
for i = 0 to 10 {
    count = count + 1
}
```

Thread T2:

```
for i = 0 to 10 {
    count = count - 1
}
```

After both are finished executing, what is the minimum and maximum value of the variable count?

My attempt to solve it: they are both accessing shared memory, so based on the race condition, whoever finishes first will have the final value. Assuming T1 finishes first every time, the maximum value of count would be 10. Assuming T2 finishes first every time, the minimum value of count would be -10. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

I think your +10 and -10 results are assuming that only one thread operates on the value, such that when you say "T1 finishes first every time" you are assuming T2 never executes. I don't think that's a reasonable assumption. I would expect the `count = count + 1` and `count = count - 1` operations to *both* be performed 10 times each.

Assuming that the `count = count + 1` (or `- 1`) operation is atomic, this question seems to be the same as asking "What is the min and max sum for any permutation of 10 +1s and 10 -1s?" I.e,. the T1 and T2 operations could be interleaved in any combination. Off the top of my head it seems to me that the net result would be 0 in all cases, but since this seems very much like a homework assignment I'll leave that for you to work out.

Comment: no im assuming both are executed, but because of the race condition, only the one that finishes first will write the final value of count

Comment: Ok. My "assuming the operation is atomic" part was meant to exclude the race condition.

If you want to include the race condition as a factor we need more information about the context. Not only could the `=` action be interleaved (so one overwrites the other) but depending upon the data type of `count` the `+` . and `-` operations might be interleaved (such that you + one "word" of the value and - another)

Comment: More generally, I think the abstract answer is to take whatever chunk of:

1. the assignment to `count`
2. the "read" of the value of `count`
3. the operation +1 or -1

you can assume to be atomic, and imagine all the ways you could shuffle those steps together.

Comment: I figured it out. The correct answer is -10 and 10. If at any time there is an interrupt between load count and store count, then the other thread gets the CPU and runs to completion. Then the original thread gets the CPU back and the last value it had is still is in a register, so it overwrites whatever the other thread did.